# How to predict customer churn (attrition) one month after start date?

Tags: r, regression, classification, survival, churn

I am trying to understand the strength of impact of variables on customer churn (attrition). I want to predict the probability that a customer will churn  after time period *t* (after 1 months, after 3 months) from start date of service.

My intention is not to predict how many customers will churn in next month.
Instead, I want predict outcome given a customer start date and other variable. I need to know the probability of churn after one month from start date (customer will stay for one month before churn).
Can I use linear regression or survival analysis methods?
Explaining the predictive ability of variables is also important to me.

My data looks like this, i have several independent variables. 
date format is mm/dd/yyyy

```
id  start_date var1 var2   end_date
1   1/1/2018    30   2     2/15/2018
2   1/24/2018   5    9     2/10/2018
3   3/2/2018    10   3     4/26/2018
```

customer 1 and 3 stayed with us for more than 1 months. whereas customer 2 churned before spending one month with us. start date and end date can be anything in last 2 years. my target is customer will spend at least one month in our service.

Comment: Without presenting data, it is hard to offer an opinion. Would you please present some data?

Comment: I have updated the questions with some sample data.

Comment: Consider making a churned column with 0 (no churn) and 1 (churned). If the customer churns, does the date then represent the date of churning? What are var1 and var2? If you want to make a physical argument then we need to know what these variables represent. Put in enough data for us to make sense of it, (lots more).

Comment: encode 0 and 1 and build a classification model like logistic regression?

Comment: Don't know yet. Put in more info.

Comment: Actually I can't provide specific info on the data. 
end date represents the date of churn(when he stops spending). var1 and var2 could be details about the account, location, type of account, dollar worth, count of communications sent & received, communication channel, number of products subscribed  or other measurable matrices to inform customer's performance.  
based on all the info. need to understand how likely customer will churn in within 1 month, after 1 month, after 3 months.
please let me know if i need to provide any other details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82917/discussion-between-gowtham-m-and-carl).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the end-date for all customers, then as far as I can see, you don't have censoring. Hence, you could treat the time a continuous variable (possibly consider a transformation, such as the log if it has a non-symmetric distribution), and use a linear regression model.